# Coordinates of object on circular path at an angle

Tags: trigonometry

I think I have been looking at this too long... I need help finding the $(x,y,z)$ coordinates of an object on a circular path that is tilted at an angle of $30^\circ$ from the horizontal, in a similar manner to the example on the left.

[image: tilted_circle]

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Parameterize the circle on the $x$-$y$ plane and then apply a rotation transformation to it.

Comment: [Spherical coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system).

Comment: [Spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system)

Comment: If you’re going to go the spherical coordinates route (not the most convenient IMO), [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GreatCircle.html) will be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved in Cartesian coordinates. Here I'm assuming that the $x$ axis directed rightwards and the $z$ axis is upwards, w.r.t your drawings.

The path is an intersection of a plane with the sphere, inclined at an angle $\theta$ to the $x$ axis. The plane is given by
$$z = x \tan \theta.$$

The radius $r$ is
$$r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$$
so
$$y = \pm \sqrt{r^2 - x^2 - z^2}$$
$$y = \pm \sqrt{r^2 - x^2 - x\tan^2 \theta},$$
provided $r^2 - x^2 - x\tan^2 \theta \ge 0$.